# Python, url parsing

Tags: python, regex, django, parsing, url

I have url e.g: "http://www.nicepage.com/nicecat/something"
And I need parse it, 
I use:

```
from urlparse import urlparse
url=urlparse("http://www.nicepage.com/nicecat/something")
#then I have:
#url.netloc() -- www.nicepage.com
#url.path() -- /nicecat/something
```

But I want to delete "www", and parse it little more. 
I would like to have something like this:

```
#path_without_www -- nicepage.com
#list_of_path -- list_of_path[0] -> "nicecat", list_of_path[1] -> "something"
```

Comment: `"http://www.nicepage.com/nicecat/something".split('/')[2:]`

Comment: split, splice and related string handling seem to do all you want to do. Is there a reason you don't want to use them? What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
import re
from urlparse import urlparse

url = urlparse('http://www.nicepage.com/nicecat/something')
url = url._replace(netloc=re.sub(r'^(www.)(.*)', r'\2', url.netloc))
```

The regex strips the 'www.' from the beginning of the netloc. From there you can parse it more as you wish.

Comment: There is no need to use regular expression. Last line can be replaced with `url._replace(netloc=url.netloc.lstrip('www.'))`

Comment: Yes, using lstrip removes the dependency on `regex`, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following would remove any leading `www` and split the remaining elements for further processing:

```
print url.netloc.lstrip("www.").split(".")
```

Giving:

```
['nicepage', 'com']
```